# Exception: Non-exhaustive patterns in function

Tags: haskell, functional-programming, runtime-error

Attempting to create a function that removes duplicates from a list, and replaces them with a single element. Keep getting an error message "Non-exhaustive patterns in function removeduplicate". I assume that means my pattern matching is missing a possible case? I think I've covered all the possibilities though. I'm very new to Haskell, so any help is greatly appreciated.

```
removeduplicate :: (Eq a) => [a] -> [a]
removeduplicate [] = []
removeduplicate (x:[]) = [x]
removeduplicate (x:z:[]) = if z == x then [x] else (x:z:[])
removeduplicate (x:y:[xs])
    | x == y = x:(removeduplicate [xs])
    | otherwise = x:y:(removeduplicate [xs])
```

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Your problem is in your final pattern.  I assume it is meant to match all lists, but the way you have it, it is matching a list with one element, `xs`, in it.

This means the compiler is seeing a match for a 3 element list, but not for an arbitrary length list, which is why it is complaining.

To fix this, remove the box around `xs`.

```
removeduplicate (x:y:xs)
    | x == y = x:(removeduplicate xs)
    | otherwise = x:y:(removeduplicate xs)
```

Now `xs` is treated as a list, so you are matching lists with *at least* three items, rather than just three items.

Answer (score 5):

As Matt Bryant said, the particular compiler error stems from using `[xs]` instead of `xs`.

You actually have a redundant pattern in there, as well:

```
removeduplicate (x:z:[]) if z == x then [x] else (x:z:[])
```

This line can be removed, because a pattern of type `x:y:[]` is already handled by

```
removeduplicate (x:y:xs)
    | x == y = x:(removeduplicate xs)
    | otherwise = x:y:(removeduplicate xs)
```

Since `xs` can be the empty list and `removeduplicate []` resolves into `[]`.

Keep in mind, though, that the code you provided only removes up to 2 successive duplicate elements. With three successive duplicates, two identical elements will be inserted into the result, which is probably not what you want.

A more complete function could look something like this:

```
removeduplicate []     = []
removeduplicate (x:xs) = x:(removeduplicate $ dropWhile (== x) xs)
```